# how to call subsection in autoref?

Tags: autoref

I wonder if there any option to call subsection or subsubsection in a way of using `\autoref{}`?

For example:

```
\subsection{Basic Structure}
.....
.....
.....

According to \autoref{\subsection{Basic Structure}}....
.....
.....
```

Thanks,
Tommy

Comment: Off-topic: You have answers to most of your questions, but accepted not a single one up to now nor cast any upvote (which is possible, since your reputation is > 15). Please accept answers to your questions and upvote them (and no, I don't have answered one of your questions (yet) ;-)) in order to appreciate the work done by users to help you

Comment: Please show us always a MWE not only a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should look like this:

```
\subsection{Basic Structure} \label{sec:basic} % choose a suitable "label"
.....
According to \autoref{sec:basic}, \dots
```

Answer (score 2):

`\autoref` is a `hyperref` extension of the `\label`-`\ref`-mechanism. So you have to set a `\label` after `\subsection` and use the argument of `\label` as argument of `\autoref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\label{sec:test}

\blindtext

\subsection{Test subsection}
\label{ssec:test}

\blindtext

This is \autoref{ssec:test} in \autoref{sec:test} with headline ``\nameref{ssec:test}''.
\end{document}
```

[image]